# How save dd-mm-yyyy date format to mysql using grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

In my grails application i use a javascript calendar plugin which accepts date in dd-mm-yyyy format. I converted the date into yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z  before saving to database which is the default date format in grails. But still it gives me an error of Invalid date format. I tried changing the 
default.date.format  in messages.properties file. But still it not works. How can i save the dd-mm-yyy format to Mysql using grails?

Answer (score 0):

try using the binding annotation on your domain class

```
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
...
class MyClass{
   @BindingFormat('dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm a')
   Date dummydate
}
```

in the `@BindingFormat` annotation you can put the format you use client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", params.date)
```

In case you want to save it to database without time we can do

```
Date.parse("dd-MM-yyyy", params.date).clearTime()
```